# CDI with Non Quarkus Spring Jars

Tags: quarkus

We are trying to migrate our application from Spring to Quarkus Spring. We are Ok to re-write our application logic as Required.
Problem comes as we are using shared spring jars which are legacy and there are many in numbers. Most spring jars are using Dependency Injection using @Autowired, but corresponding class that is getting injected does not have @Component Annotations.

Will describe problem with example:

> Class "MyProject" belong to Quarkus Applicatioin

```
public class MyProject {
    
    @Autowired
    private OtherLevelOne otherLevelOne;

    public void invokeMe() {
        this.otherLevelOne.call();
    }
}
```

> Class OtherLevelOne and OtherLevelTwo belongs to a dependency spring jar.

```
public class OtherLevelOne {
    
    @Autowired
    private OtherLevelTwo otherLevelTwo;

    

public void call() {
        this.otherLevelTwo.otherCall();
    }
}

public class OtherLevelTwo {
    
    public void otherCall() {
        
    }
}
```

> Issue Faced.

```
During compilation of Quakrus Application we get error:
```

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:2.1.3.Final:build (quarkus-app-build) on project service-quarkus: Failed to build quarkus application: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
[ERROR]     [error]: Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor#validate threw an exception: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: Found 2 deployment problems:
[ERROR] [1] Unsatisfied dependency for type OtherLevelOne and qualifiers [@Default]
```

> Things Tried: Added a Producer class for Both OtherLevelOne and OtherLevelTwo. This helped in resolving the Compile time Unsatisfied dependency issue and Build was success. But now we faced a NullPointException as runtime when method "call" of OtherLevelOne tried to access the instance of "OtherLevelTwo". So Looks like second level injection did not happen. Possibly Quarkus does not support this (without some modifications like adding beans.xml and @Component annotations to all the classes in dependency jars).

```
@Dependent
public class ProducerClass {

    @Produces
    public OtherLevelOne createOtherLevelOne() {
        return new OtherLevelOne();
    }

    @Produces
    public OtherLevelTwo createOtherLevelTwo(){
        return new OtherLevelTwo();
    }
}
```

> **Question**

1. Is there a way we can make Quarkus work in this scenario without compiling all the dependencies with Quarkus?
2. Is it possible to write a Quarkus extenstion that can help in achieving Dependency Injection of required Types?

Thanks.

Comment: The way you have described the code, that should not work in pure Spring either. I mean that there must be some place where you are making the unannotated classes Spring beans. How is that achieved?

Comment: The class is defined as a bean as part of applicationContext.xml. That might be the reason for it getting Autowired.

Answer (score 0):

In quarkus configuration via XML is not supported, so you will need to create a producer method to make `OtherLevelOne` and `OtherLevelTwo` beans

Comment: As mentioned above:

Things Tried: Added a Producer class for Both OtherLevelOne and OtherLevelTwo. This helped in resolving the Compile time Unsatisfied dependency issue and Build was success. But now we faced a NullPointException as runtime when method "call" of OtherLevelOne tried to access the instance of "OtherLevelTwo". So Looks like second level injection did not happen. Possibly Quarkus does not support this (without some modifications like adding beans.xml and @Component annotations to all the classes in dependency jars).

Comment: Hi @geoand, there is any other way I can achieve this or above approach should have worked?